# How to get Sales Cloud field tracking data into Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, field-history, data-synchronization

The problem: we want to have a journey that triggers on leads getting a certain status. All leads that currently already have that status, should not be submitted to the journey. So we thought: just enable field tracking on leads, synchronize the data to Marketing Cloud and create a SQL action over there.

In Sales Cloud we have the LeadHistory object and we can query it with SOQL. We see the relevant status changes.

Now how to get this data into Marketing Cloud? Currently we have five synchronized data sources: four standard objects and one custom object.

Clicking "+ Set Up Object" shows the "Synchronize Entity" screen with 287 available entities. But no History entities! In Sales Cloud we have field tracking enabled for several objects, but no History object is available in Marketing Cloud.

[This Salesforce help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5) may give the reason:

> To ensure that the object is available to sync, these criteria must be
> met:
>
> ```
> Queryable: True
> Creatable: True
> Retrievable: True
> Replicateable: True
> CustomSetting: False
> ```

I guess History objects are not Creatable.

So how do I get access to field tracking data in Marketing Cloud?

I know we could also solve our problem with a suppression list, but I can think of several use cases where it's easier just to query the field tracking history instead of creating a suppression list.

Comment: I am trying to understand how you determine if a Lead record supposes to enter to the journey. If it depends on specific fields in the Lead object, then journey builder can trigger like what you want

Comment: @DucLe We want Leads to enter a journey when they get into a certain state. But leads that are already in that state should not enter the journey. If the entry criteria of the journey only look at the state, then leads enter the journey that should not enter. So you need either a suppression list or access to the changes in a lead.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly your situation but if you are using Salesforce data entry source with Update action, then the journey won't trigger injection with qualified Lead. The record must first not qualify, and then be updated to qualify in order to inject to the journey https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382915&type=1

Comment: @DucLe is right, the journey will only admit records that change after the journey activation

Comment: The problem is that leads can change for a variety of reasons, but for one particular journey we are only interested in certain status changes. What we see is that "old" leads, that have had that status for a long time, are updated with respect to other fields. Marketing Cloud sees an update, sees the proper status and lets the lead enter the journey, but that should not happen. Only leads whose status is changed into a certain status should enter the journey. That's where access to LeadHistory would be useful.

Comment: I don’t think that’s how it’s supposed to work - maybe your journey is incorrectly configured? It should only react to that one field change, it should not be triggered by other fields if they are not included in the entry criteria

Comment: At first I did not understand the comments on my post. Then I started reading about "Salesforce Data Event as an Entry Source" and they started to make sense. I had never heard of this feature. In our org, we use journeys with Data Extensions, SQL activities and automations. Salesforce Data Event as an Entry Source are a good solution for simple journeys, but we have complicated journeys that rely on up-to-date Sales Cloud data. Salesforce Data Event as an Entry Source do not support that, they copy data at the start of a journey.